# Is there anyway to format a string made from the map function?

Tags: python-3.x

Here is my code:

```
menu=[['1.PEPPERONI  ' ,                              8.50],
['2.SIMPLY CHEESE  ' ,                           8.50],
['3.GARLIC CHEESE  ' ,                           8.50],
['4.HAM & CHEESE  ' ,                            8.50],
['5.VEG TRIO ' ,                                 8.50],
['6.BEEF & ONION  ' ,                            8.50],
['7.HAWAIIAN  ' ,                                8.50],
['8.APRICOT CHICKEN  ' ,                         13.50],
['9.MEATLOVERS  ' ,                              13.50],
['10.PERI-PERI CHICKEN  ' ,                      13.50],
['11.PHILLY STEAK AND CHEESE  ' ,                13.50],
['12.CHICKEN & CRANBERRY  ' ,                    13.50]]

for i in menu:
  o='$'.join(map(str, i))
  print(o)
```

I used the map function to turn my menu 2D list into a real menu ( I am trying to turn my 2D list menu into a real menu text-based and the prices must all be formatted vertically). The string result doesn't contain bracket or comma which is good but I need the prices to be formatted vertically. In short, the result should look like a real menu and must be easy for customer to read. Is there any way to format it?

Answer (score 1):

Why use `map` and `join`? It's more straightforward to simply left- and right-justify using the [format-specification mini-language](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language)

```
for i in menu:
    o = f"{i[0]:<30}${i[1]:>5.2f}"
    print(o)
```

Explanation:

- `f"..."`: Denotes an [f-string](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/)
- `{i[0]:<30}`: left-justify `i[0]` to a length of 30
- `{i[1]:>5.2f}`:

  - `f` => format `i[1]` as a float
  - `.2` => with 2 decimal places
  - `>5`: right-justify the resulting string to a length of 5

Output:

```
1.PEPPERONI                   $ 8.50
2.SIMPLY CHEESE               $ 8.50
3.GARLIC CHEESE               $ 8.50
4.HAM & CHEESE                $ 8.50
5.VEG TRIO                    $ 8.50
6.BEEF & ONION                $ 8.50
7.HAWAIIAN                    $ 8.50
8.APRICOT CHICKEN             $13.50
9.MEATLOVERS                  $13.50
10.PERI-PERI CHICKEN          $13.50
11.PHILLY STEAK AND CHEESE    $13.50
12.CHICKEN & CRANBERRY        $13.50
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `str.format` with [format string syntax](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/string.html#format-string-syntax):

```
menu=[['1.PEPPERONI  ' ,                              8.50],
['2.SIMPLY CHEESE  ' ,                           8.50],
['3.GARLIC CHEESE  ' ,                           8.50],
['4.HAM & CHEESE  ' ,                            8.50],
['5.VEG TRIO ' ,                                 8.50],
['6.BEEF & ONION  ' ,                            8.50],
['7.HAWAIIAN  ' ,                                8.50],
['8.APRICOT CHICKEN  ' ,                         13.50],
['9.MEATLOVERS  ' ,                              13.50],
['10.PERI-PERI CHICKEN  ' ,                      13.50],
['11.PHILLY STEAK AND CHEESE  ' ,                13.50],
['12.CHICKEN & CRANBERRY  ' ,                    13.50]]

for name, price in menu:
    print('{:<50} ${:0.2f}'.format(name, price))
```

Prints:

```
1.PEPPERONI                                        $8.50
2.SIMPLY CHEESE                                    $8.50
3.GARLIC CHEESE                                    $8.50
4.HAM & CHEESE                                     $8.50
5.VEG TRIO                                         $8.50
6.BEEF & ONION                                     $8.50
7.HAWAIIAN                                         $8.50
8.APRICOT CHICKEN                                  $13.50
9.MEATLOVERS                                       $13.50
10.PERI-PERI CHICKEN                               $13.50
11.PHILLY STEAK AND CHEESE                         $13.50
12.CHICKEN & CRANBERRY                             $13.50
```